# How do I pass variables into short-code enabled Post Snippets in Wordpress 3.0?

Tags: variables

I am using a plugin called Post Snippets.

According to the documentation, it can substitute variables, such as {url} within the snippets.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-snippets/

I am unclear how to assign values from within a specific post to a variable.

I tried using exec-PHP, and used the following:

```
[exec]url = "domain.com";[/exec]
```

But the snippet registered no value for {url}.

**How can I assign, from within a post, the value to a variable so that I can use it as described?**

Answer (score 1):

The *Variables* in [Post Snippets (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-snippets/) is a comma seperated value. When you use the snippet-insert button in the post/page editor, you can set those.

An example of this is given on the homepage of the plugin, there is even a screenshot demonstrating that. [Please read the documentation first](http://wpstorm.net/wordpress-plugins/post-snippets/).

Those *Post Snippet Variables* are totally unrelated to PHP variables. I think that's just the thing you missed. You were looking in the wrong direction.

Comment: I am using shortcode...how do I pass the variables through a short code, I don't want to insert the actual html....

Comment: Hmm...that being said, can I change the url variables to be $vars so I can use php code?

Comment: @timothy: as for the plugin, from a view from above, I think it's not possible out of the box. You might hack into the plugin, overload the shortcode and then pass some variable value (e.g. via a shortcode attribute) into the plugin. But I have not reviewed the plugins sourcecode if and how this is possible. If you enter the shortcode with some values, this *might* reveal how this is working.